# can't connect to wifi using Xubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, xubuntu, internet

Everytime i try to connect to internet using wifi i type the password, Xubuntu tries to connect for a little while and then asks me the password again. I'm using a D-Link modem/router.

```
Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvA Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8171] (rev 10)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1467]
 Kernel driver in use: rtl8192se
```

Please guys i really need some help here, if i don't get this working i will have to go back to Windows.

Comment: What gives you in terminal rfkill list ?

Answer (score 0):

When asked for the password the second time, the D-Link modem-router is asking you for its password.  You'll have to find that password in order to continue and connect.